# Creating RadioGroup programmatically

Tags: android, android-view, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I'm getting an Error while working with the following code

> Error: The specified child already has a parent you must call removeView on the child's parent first

Anyone please help me in resolving this
Error:

```java
RadioButton[] radiobutton = new RadioButton[5];
RadioGroup radiogroup = new RadioGroup(this);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    LinearLayout listmainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.phonelist);
    // listmainLayout.setLayoutParams(new
    // ListView.LayoutParams(width,
    // height / 10));
    listmainLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    RelativeLayout mainlistLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainlistLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        (int) (width * 0.85), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mainlistLayout.setLayoutParams(mainlistLayoutParams);
    // mainlistLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    mainlistLayout.setPadding((int) (0.03 * width), 0, 0, 0);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams radiogroupparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    radiogroup.setLayoutParams(radiogroupparams);
    radiobutton[i] = new RadioButton(this);
    radiobutton[i].setText(" " + ContactsActivity.phonetype.get(i)
        + "    " + ContactsActivity.phone.get(i));
    radiobutton[i].setId(i + 100);
    radiogroup.removeView(radiobutton[i]);
    radiogroup.addView(radiobutton[i]);
    mainlistLayout.addView(radiogroup);
}
```

My logcat shows:

```
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.contacts_appetite/com.example.contacts_appetite.ContactDetalisList}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3378)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3249)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3194)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3170)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at com.example.contacts_appetite.ContactDetalisList.getView(ContactDetalisList.java:139)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at com.example.contacts_appetite.ContactDetalisList.onCreate(ContactDetalisList.java:65)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-12 17:51:11.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3353):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: i think this is wrong RadioButton[] radiobutton = new RadioButton[ContactsActivity.phone
                .size()];

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096329/get-the-array-of-radiobuttons-in-a-radiogroup-in-android

Comment: and layout which u set for radiogroup that will outside the loop, because radiogroup layout set one time now u add ur buttons in group, so no need to add radiogroup in  loop

Answer (score 84, accepted):

this `The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` because you are adding child( radio group ) to the parent layout multiple times.

try like this

```
private void createRadioButton() {
    final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); //create the RadioGroup
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
       rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);          
       rb[i].setText(" " + ContactsActivity.phonetype.get(i)
            + "    " + ContactsActivity.phone.get(i));
       rb[i].setId(i + 100);
       rg.addView(rb[i]);
    }
    ll.addView(rg);//you add the whole RadioGroup to the layout

}
```

Comment: why do you have `rg.addView(rb[i])` before setting text and id? also you are adding view to rg again at the end

Comment: yes. that will work... and adding RadioGroup at the end to the parent Layout.

Comment: For me, it worked only after removing "rg.addView(radiobutton[i]);"

Comment: I am also trying this solution but using this way radio group allowing me to select all radio button inside it. It should be only single selection of radio button within the same radio group.

Answer (score 23):

Here is my source code,

**First Create String arrays**

```
<string-array name="websites_array">
    <item>Yahoo</item>
    <item>Hotmail</item>
    <item>Gmail</item>
    <item>Facebook</item>
    <item>Other</item>
</string-array>
```

**Then in source code,**

```
final RadioGroup radioGrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    //get string array from source
    String[] websitesArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.websites_array);

    //create radio buttons
    for (int i = 0; i < websitesArray.length; i++) {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButton.setText(websitesArray[i]);
        radioButton.setId(i);
        radioGrp.addView(radioButton);
    }

    //set listener to radio button group
    radioGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int checkedRadioButtonId = radioGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton radioBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedRadioButtonId);
            Toast.makeText(ConfigurationActivity.this, radioBtn.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

That's all... :)

Comment: What is the point in calling ```getCheckedRadioButtonId()``` if you already have the ```checkedId```?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
RadioButton[] radiobutton = new RadioButton[5];
  final  RadioGroup radiogroup = new RadioGroup(this);

LinearLayout listmainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.phonelist);
        // listmainLayout.setLayoutParams(new
        // ListView.LayoutParams(width,
        // height / 10));
        listmainLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        RelativeLayout mainlistLayout = new RelativeLayout(
                getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainlistLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int) (width * 0.85), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mainlistLayout.setLayoutParams(mainlistLayoutParams);
        // mainlistLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        mainlistLayout.setPadding((int) (0.03 * width), 0, 0, 0);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams radiogroupparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        radiogroup.setLayoutParams(radiogroupparams);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {


        radiobutton[i] = new RadioButton(this);
        radiobutton[i].setText(" " + ContactsActivity.phonetype.get(i)
                + "    " + ContactsActivity.phone.get(i));
        radiobutton[i].setId(i + 100);
        radiogroup.addView(radiobutton[i]);
        mainlistLayout.addView(radiogroup);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add array to strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="some_array">
    <item>some_item_0</item>
    <item>some_item_1</item>
    <item>some_item_2</item>
</string-array>
```

I don't think you need id but text for each button so put somewhere this method (in my case this is Utils class):

```
public static void fillRadioGroup(Context context, RadioGroup radioGroup, int stringArrayId){
    for (String s : context.getResources().getStringArray(stringArrayId)){
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(context);
        radioButton.setText(s);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }

    if(radioGroup.getChildCount() > 0)
        radioGroup.check(radioGroup.getChildAt(0).getId());
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
Utils.fillRadioGroup(this, radioGroup, R.array.some_array);
```

To get text you need to call:

```
if(radioGroup.getChildCount() > 0)
    String text = ((RadioButton) findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class RadioButtonsGroup {

    private val buttons = ArrayList<RadioButton>()

    fun add(radioButton: RadioButton) {
        buttons.add(radioButton)

        radioButton.setOnClickListener {
            for (button in buttons) {
                if (radioButton !== button) {
                    button.isChecked = false
                }
            }

            radioButton.isChecked = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String selectedValue = "";
    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList; //or replace your list here
    arrayList.add("Apple");
    arrayList.add("Melon");

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
       RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
       radioButton.setText(arrayList.get(i));
       radioGroup.addView(radioButton);

       int keyI = i;
       radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (radioButton.isChecked()){
                   selectedValue = arrayList.get(keyI);
                   Toast.makeText(AnActivity.this,selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
       });
    }
    linearLayout.addView(radioGroup);
    //to do with updated selectedValue
```