# Generate dynamic RadioGroup programatically and setOnCheckedChangeListener on it

Tags: java, android, hashmap, radio-button, android-radiogroup

I Made below Code for Displaying Dynamic Radiogroup and radiobuttons.
But I cannot understand how to get checked button into `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` method.
Some time multiple RadioButton will click on same RadioGroup.
I don't know how?

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

menuSize = 4;

for(i = 0; i < menuSize; i++)
{
    int menuId = controller.getMenuid(i));
    int subMenuSize = controller.getSubMenu(menuId).size();  // Dynamic value from MVC architechture

    TextView textViewHeading = new TextView(getApplicationContext()); // RadioGroup Heading
    textViewHeading.setText(controller.getMenuName(i));    // Set RadioGroup Heading

    linearLayout.addView(textViewHeading);

    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext());
    radioGroup.setId(i);

    for(j = 0; j < subMenuSize; j++)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());

        radioButton.setId(j);

        // Get value from HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<SubMenuClass>>
        // Value is used for RadioButton
        radioButton.setText( controller.getSubMenu(menuId).get(j).getSubMenuName()); 

        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(TryRadioButtons.this);

    linearLayout.addView(radioGroup);
}
```

I want to check on ButtonSubmit Click that every RadioGroup have one RadioButton must checked.
So how can I get that RadioButton in ButtonSubmit ClickEvent?

Thnks in Advance

Comment: You have to start with the linear layout like here on the first line and then loop through its children.

Comment: I want to get radiobuttons in setOnCheckedChangeListener() method

Comment: Yes i know. I knew that already. You dont have to say that again. What did yoy do with my suggestion?

Comment: I solved it. In my code there is problem is in setId. I set ID the value of "i" and "j" that will may b same for sometime. so it will check multiple radiobuttons in same radiogroup. by d way thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Refer this..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929295/creating-radiogroup-programmatically)

May be it will help you for getting radiobutton dynamically

Answer (score 1):

do this way,

```
RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(this); 
group.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
RadioButton btn1 = new RadioButton(this);
btn1.setText("BTN1");
group.addView(btn1);
RadioButton btn2 = new RadioButton(this);
group.addView(btn2);
btn2.setText("BTN2");
.... 
RadioButton btnN = new RadioButton(this);
group.addView(btnN);
btnN.setText("BTNN");
yourLayout.addView(group);
```