# How can i add RadioButton to the RadioGroup by java?

Tags: java, android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

> It maybe a very simple question but i am beginner in Android please help with it.

i have created two `RadioButton`s in XML without `RadioGroup` and in `MainActivity.java` created a `RadioGroup`, how can i add both `RadioButton`s in that `RadioGroup`? Code is below...

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.avisingh.radiobuttontest.MainActivity">

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/male_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Male"/>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/female_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="Female"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.avisingh.radiobuttontest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final RadioButton maleBtn = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.male_button);
    final RadioButton femaleBtn = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.female_button);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);

    //radioGroup.add(maleBtn); // its getting error
    //radioGroup.add(femaleBtn); // its getting error
    //radioGroup.addView(maleBtn); // it is also getting error
    //radioGroup.addView(femaleBtn); // it is also getting error

    }
}
```

is there any method too add both `RadioButton`s like java?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929295/creating-radiogroup-programmatically

Comment: i have already checked here, the both `RadioButton`s are placed in a `RadioGroup` but actually i want to add them by java like `JRadioButton`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating RadioGroup programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929295/creating-radiogroup-programmatically)

Comment: Use `radioGroup.addView()`

Comment: `radioGroup.addView()` is also getting error...!!!

Comment: Compile error or runtime error?

Comment: runtime error, if you allow me then posting the errors here..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151985/discussion-between-avinash-kumar-and-bob).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it

```
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
    radioButton.setText("Test Radio");
    radioButton.setId(1);
    radioGrp.addView(radioButton);
```

if its too many try putting it into loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i < radioItems.length; i++) {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButton.setText(radioItems[i]);
        radioButton.setId(i);
        radioGrp.addView(radioButton);
    }
```

Comment: but is it not a new `RadioButton` ?  i only want to add these `RadioButton`s that i have  created in XML without `RadioGroup`

Comment: Then instead of radio group use linear layout or relative layout and call addView() on it. Because in anyway you have to add your radio button under some parent view.

Answer (score 0):

you can add 'RadioGroup' inside the 'activity_main.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.avisingh.radiobuttontest.MainActivity">
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioSex"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/male_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Male"/>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/female_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="Female"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: actually i am asking about how can i add both `RadioButton`s by java not xml.