# Android java - is it possible to get text from RadioButton in RadioGroup without each RadioButton having a defined id?

Tags: java, android, xml, text, radio-button

For android programming, I have a RadioGroup which contains some RadioButtons.
I want to just get the text from the button without need to get the id of the RadioButton.

```
<RadioGroup
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
      >

      <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1"
        />

      <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2"
       />

      <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text3"
        />

    </RadioGroup>
```

Is it possible to just get the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all Views within a RadioGroup with this code:

```
    int count = radioGroup.getChildCount(); 
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
        View radioButton = radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (radioButton instanceof RadioButton) {
            Log.d(TAG,"text: "+ radioButton.getText().toString());
        }
    }
```

reference: [Get the array of RadioButtons in a RadioGroup in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5096359/11691547)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible.
Why don't you just provide id to each radiobutton ?

Comment: I can do that, but it takes more time and work. I guess I could just copy-paste all generic ids.